# in Angular how to change the input content to another format and then display that format

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The original practice of W3CSchool--Angular Service. I want to advance that practice by transforming the content in HTML input to the hexadecimal in HTML  element. How to do it? Thanks in advance.

original version:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>The hexadecimal value of 255 is:</p>
<h1>{{hex}}</h1>
</div>
<!--A custom service with a method that converts a given number into a hexadecimal number.-->

<script>//angular
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); //create module

app.service('hexafy', function() {   //create a custom service
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {  //create a controller
  $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc(255);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

my advanced version(but failed):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>The hexadecimal value of 255 is:</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="hexInput"/>
<h1>{{hexInput}}</h1>   <!--get the value in the input-->
<h1>{{hex}}</h1>   
</div><!--A custom service with a method that converts a input number into a hexadecimal number.-->
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
  $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc($scope.hexInput);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution:

You need to subscribe to the input change to calculate the value each time you put something into input, not just once on controller initialization. We do this by `ng-change='calculateHex()'`.

You need to check for empty string every time you calculate and if it's empty return '' without hex calculation.

The last note here is you should parse `x` as a number first because it comes as a string from ng-model. Then do `.toString()` again.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Input number</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="hexInput" ng-change="calculateHex()"/>
<h1>The hexadecimal value is: <span style="text-transform: uppercase">{{hex}}</span></h1>   
</div><!--A custom service with a method that converts a input number into a hexadecimal number.-->
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return parseInt(x, 10).toString(16);
    }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
      $scope.calculateHex = function() {
         $scope.hex = $scope.hexInput && $scope.hexInput.length && hexafy.myFunc($scope.hexInput) || '';
      }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, give me one sec.

Comment: Could you please explain   $scope.hex = $scope.hexInput && $scope.hexInput.length && hexafy.myFunc($scope.hexInput) || '';  to me? Why $scope.hex=$scope.hexInput&&$scope.hexInput.length ? I can understand $scope.hex=hexafy.myFunc($scope.hexInput) || ''.

Comment: First is check for undefined and null then check for empty string

Comment: You shouldn’t call hex function if the data is incorrect

Comment: It’s just syntax sugar . Hex function will not be called until both are true and if they false , empty string will be set instead.

Comment: So if the input is defined($scope.hexInput==true) and it is not null($scope.hexInput.length==ture), it will execute hexafy.myFunc($scope.hexInput), otherwise it will treat $scope.hex as empty. Can I understand by that?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you said.